# How to create Logic apps using API?

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

We are doing implementation of Logic App in our application. We have tried out the logic apps from azure portal and it is working alright. Due to business requirement we need to have capability to logic app using API. After much search in documentation I was not able to find on how to create logic apps using API. How can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

Depends on what your needs are for an API.  From a basic standpoint Logic Apps can be created as part of the [Azure Resource Management APIs](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-logic-create-deploy-template/) which is used to script or create any Azure resource from an API call.

There is also the [Logic Apps SDK](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Management.Logic/) which is an extension of the resource management and gives you access to things like "create new", "disable", "enable", etc.  Similar story with PowerShell.

Do any of these work for your business requirements?

Comment: Forgot to mention, we hare working with PHP. Anything available with PHP SDK?

Comment: Closest we have for now would be that Resource Manager Deployment I mentioned can be used from a [xplat CLI](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/xplat-cli-azure-resource-manager/) (Node.JS CLI).  The Logic App SDK is currently being ported to the xplat CLI and should be there within the month for the SDK functionality within the CLI.  But all of the operations from the SDK and other pieces are just wrappers on top of the [REST API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt643788.aspx) that could be used today.